# Lambda issue with increase max size of autoscaling group

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

trying to create a Lambda function with boto3 and increase my scaling group via lambda.

```
import boto3
region = 'us-east-1'
asgname = 'ASG'
autoscaling = boto3.client('autoscaling')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
autoscaling.update_auto_scaling_groups(AutoScalingGroupName=ASG, MaxSize=4)
print('Thank You')
```

Comment: Please post the error. Need more description of the problem.

Comment: START RequestId: 2aacb39e-bbeb-4ed1-b072-44514b6e5d7e Version: $LATEST
/var/task/bootstrap: line 23: ./handler.sh: No such file or directory
END RequestId: 2aacb39e-bbeb-4ed1-b072-44514b6e5d7e
REPORT RequestId: 2aacb39e-bbeb-4ed1-b072-44514b6e5d7e Duration: 215.02 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 39 MB Init Duration: 38.97 ms 
RequestId: 2aacb39e-bbeb-4ed1-b072-44514b6e5d7e Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError

Comment: I hope that you have created an autoscaling group with the name ASG. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the code like below and try:

```
import boto3
region = 'us-east-1'
asgname = 'ASG'
autoscaling = boto3.client('autoscaling')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    autoscaling.update_auto_scaling_group(AutoScalingGroupName=asgname, MaxSize=4)
    print('Thank You')
```

I was able to make it work successfully.